# Connecting Netbeans 7.3 to Microsoft SQL server Management Studio Express database

Tags: java, sql-server

I need to connect my half build GUI Netbeans project to a Microsoft SQL server Management Studio Express database... I am creating an application in Netbeans that will be used by a librarian who can thus keep track of the books issued, customer details, etc... How do i connect the two of them?

Answer (score 0):

You can download at http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21599. After download, extract the file. On netbeans (after you open the netbeans application), open form services. On there, you can create new driver with custome. Select file sqljdbc4.jar (at the extract file). Next, you can see the new driver for Microsoft SQL Server 200x. For test connection, right click at the driver. Then, setting in accordance with the form shown